# Show that $\int_{c}\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^{2}} =2\pi i\bigl(\frac{\pi}{\sinh^{2}\pi} -\frac{1}{\pi}\bigr)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that
$$
\int_{c}\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^{2}} =
2\pi i\left(\frac{\pi}{\sinh^{2}\pi} -\frac{1}{\pi}\right),
$$
where $c$ is the contour $4x^{2}+y^{2}=2$ (counter clockwise). I tried to prove it using Cauchy Integral formula as:

$$\int\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^{2}}=2\pi if'(i)$$

$$
f'(i)=\frac{-\pi}{\sin^{2}\pi z}
\int\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^{2}}=
2\pi i \frac{-\pi}{\sin^{2}\pi z}
$$

I don't know where I am going wrong. I don't even know how to draw the given curve. Please help.

Comment: I hope you're busy sorting out the MathJax code here

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

There are two poles enclosed by the ellipse $4x^2+y^2=2$; one at $z=0$ and the other at $z=i$.

The pole at $z=0$ is of order one, while the pole at $z=i$ is of order two.

Now, use the residue theorem to write the integral in terms of the sum of the two residues.

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> We have from the residue theorem $$\int_{4x^2+y^2=2}\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2}\,dz=2\pi i \left(\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2}, z=0\right)+\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2}, z=i\right)\right)$$The residue at $z=0$ is trivially $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z \cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2}=-1/\pi$.  The residue at $z=i$ is  $\lim_{z\to i}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{(z-i)^2 \cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2}\right)=\lim_{z\to i}(-\pi \csc^2(i\pi))=\frac{\pi }{\sinh^2(\pi)}$.  Putting it all together, we find that $$\int_{4x^2+y^2=2}\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{(z-i)^2}\,dz=2\pi i\left(\frac{\pi }{\sinh^2(\pi)}-\frac{1}{\pi}\right)$$as was to be shown!

Comment: it gives same answer 2\pi i(\frac{-\pi}{sin^{2}\pi z}) because Res(0)=0 and Res(i)=\frac{-\pi}{sin^{2}\pi z}

Comment: isn't there something wrong in the given problem?

Comment: @T.Noor The problem is well posed.  See the development in the spoiler alert section if needed.  -Mark

Comment: yes sir..thank you very much for help

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.